# inline functions in c

Tags: c, compiler-errors, inline

i have inline c swap function for sorting an array
but in the compile time it gives error
that swap reference is undefined.
by removing the swap it works;
what is wrong with code

```
inline void swap(int* a, int* b)
{
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

void sort(int ar[])
{
    int length = sizeof(ar) / sizeof(int);
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = i; j < length; j++)
        {
            if(ar[j] < ar[i])
            {
                swap(&ar[j], &ar[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't get the length of a passed array with `sizeof`. You have to explictly pass it via a parameter.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but `sizeof(ar) / sizeof(int)` is flawed. It's because `ar` is a *pointer*, and doing `sizeof` on a pointer returns the size of the pointer itself and not the data it points to. You need to explicitly pass the size of your array as an argument to the function.

Comment: use this before function definition..    void swap(int *, int *) __attribute__((always_inline));

Comment: @amitpandey That is *very* compiler dependent.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
int length = sizeof(ar) / sizeof(int);
```

Pass the length of your array instead of trying to do something (that won't work).

Remove the `inline`, it's not relevant and causes your issue. If the compiler can optimize this, it will inline it, otherwise it's just an advice you give the compiler, nothing more.

Comment: This is more of a comment, than an actual answer :/ Please expand it, so it actually answers OPs question.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude um. sorry, that comment above were supposed to go somewhere else.